# Ubuntu 13.04 How I get Menu options like Win*?

Tags: windows, menu

I am very new to Linux, trying to replace Windows 7 with a flavor of Linux, two of my Cyber frieds advised me to get Ubuntu. I got it (13.04 GNOME) and burnt on USB, boot from USB and have a very nice and clean Desktop. On left side i saw some icons to run specific Applications and Setting etc. but what about more applications / utilities which i assume to access from a Start Menu like option as in Win* and in some (Scrren Shots shows) other linux flavors. How i can access all it has?
Please help me to avoid using Windows.
Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Try pressing the Windows key (called "Super" in the Linux world) ;-)

Comment: thanks Seth... it is not like that but showing Options on whole desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Oralover, as you said, when you open the Gnome launcher, on your left side you can see a row of some 6 apps or so. In the same row you can see the last icon (9 white squares). Click it and you'll see the complete list of your Applications. You can scroll through it to find a desired app, or you can browse them by categories on the far right.